# SQL script for incrementing dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-arithmetic

I am not sure how to make an automaticed script that incrments all dates in a database. I was asked if the date is Friday, the script needs to increment the next business date to Monday, so I will need some logic in the script.

This can be easily done in C# or any other programming language. But, I was required that the script must be automaticed, identially a native SQL script (*.sql). I am confused whether this is possible at all.

Comment: Depending the date representation, it's usually easy: find the rows with a DayOfWeek equal to Friday; add 3 days.

Comment: So, you think I can select a list of columns for Monday, update them by one. Then, do the same for Tuesday, Wednesday etc?

Comment: whilst you are 'thinking in sets', better to think as one set operation rather than seven separate ones.  pascal's solution below performs the update in one set operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourdate = dateadd(dd, 3, yourdate)
WHERE datepart(weekday,yourdate)=6
```

you can manipulate the WHERE clause however you want. It will add 3 days to each date in your database which corresponds to your WHERE clause.

Comment: Just be careful that you check that weekday 6 is Friday on your server setup.  Alternatively you can use `DATENAME(WEEKDAY, yourdate) = 'Friday'` - again, be careful as to which language setting is used.

Comment: UPDATE yourtable
SET yourdate = dateadd(dd, CASE datepart(weekday,yourdate) WHEN 6 THEN 3 ELSE 1 END, yourdate)

Comment: Thanks, it works. You're a genius, didn't thought there would be an elegant solution like this.